# Python - Defining an integer variable over multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to define a variable that is a 1000 digits long and I'm loathe to have it all on one line. Is there a way to split an integer variable over several lines?

I have tried using different indentations and parentheses yet to no avail.

Should I just accept that the below has to be stored on one line or am I just missing something obvious?

```
num = 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
  96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
  85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
  12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
  66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
  62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
  30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
  70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
  65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
  52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
  53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
  83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
  82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
  16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
  17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
  24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
  07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
  84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
  05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
  71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Comment: you could define it as a string and then use an appropriate function to convert it to an integer - not sure if `int` would work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
num = int("""
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450""".replace("\n", ""))
```

Good luck with the Project Euler problem. :)

Comment: Genius! Thanks lazyr. I just couldn't bear having it all on one line.

Comment: Me and you both, hemmy. That's scissored straight from my own solution, except I just kept it as a string.

Comment: I see. Actually, it's not necessary to handle the 1000 digits as a very large integer in this problem

Comment: Thanks gefei I see I need it as a string so I can iterate over it... no more hints though ;)

Answer (score 6):

To clearly present your data without manipulating it, implicit concatenation allows:

```
number = ('73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934'
          '96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843'
          '85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511'
          #...
          )
```

Parentheses are necessary. Note that there are no commas, which means Python processes them in as a continuation of the same string.

Pros:

- It's clear to read.
- It appears quite unambiguous.
- It is easy to line up with the first line.
- Being lined up makes it quite easy for most IDE's to code fold.
- It avoids escaping endlines, which is considered bad form.
- It is processed directly as a string once, with no further manipulation and wasted clock cycles.

Con: Minor noise from the `'` and `()`.

---

You can then coerce the number to an integer (long integer in Python 2) with

```
number = int(number)
```

In python 3, all integers are long integers.

Answer (score 3):

Try keeping it in a string:

```
numbers = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
```

Comment: I have to say the \ kills me.